# How many percent of all nodes decided to hard fork

Tags: nodes, dao, hardforks

Where can I see the actual number of nodes that joined the hard fork, in comparison to the others, which didn't? What does the difficulty tell me about that relation? i.e. 100% : 91% [as here](http://fork.ethstats.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the blockheight difference you can see that pretty much nobody mines the nonfork chain.

Normally a block is mined every 14 secs, the difference

(Blockheight<sub>profork</sub> - Blockheight<sub>nonfork</sub>) * 14s = Time ahead

It's over 1h and gives you an idea that currently nobody mines the Nonfork chain.

Also Blockheight<sub>nonfork</sub> is currently 48 * 14s is arround 11 minutes. So nothing happens on Nonfork...

http://fork.ethstats.net/

Another nice indicator is the current hash rate

Highest [Avg Hashrate](https://etherscan.io/charts/hashrate) of 4437.5176 GH/s was recorded on Monday, July 18, 2016

And we are [quite there again](http://ethstats.net)...